# Creating a procedure with multiple parameters in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a procedure to update my database with multiple parameters. Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //    
CREATE PROCEDURE updateImages (IN stagingID INT, IN streetName VARCHAR(50), IN numberOfImages INT)

BEGIN
DECLARE count INT;
SET count = 1;

    WHILE count < (numberOfImages + 1) DO
        SET fileName = CONCAT(streetName, ' (mls) (', count, ').jpg');
        INSERT INTO images_tbl VALUES
       (NULL, stagingID, fileName, 0);
       SET count = count + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

PHPMyAdmin is giving me a blank #1193 error with no other information. I've tried to search and implement the resolutions I have found regarding this error, but have not been able to figure it out.

Any ideas would be very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: include a line for `DECLARE fileName varchar(200);` or the like. works on my system with no 1193

Comment: Oh, wow. It's always the little things that get overlooked. Thank you @Drew!  Edit: Now I am getting a blank #1064 error, which I think is the syntax error?  I declared the fileName below the count declaration

Comment: aint that the truth JG

Comment: Second Edit: Nevermind, I had something else wrong. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

As @Drew pointed out, I omitted a declaration for fileName. Final Code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateImages (IN stagingID INT, IN streetName VARCHAR(50), IN numberOfImages INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT;
    DECLARE fileName VARCHAR(100);
    SET count = 1;

    WHILE count < (numberOfImages + 1) DO        
        SET fileName = CONCAT(streetName, ' (mls) (', count, ').jpg');
        INSERT INTO images_tbl VALUES (NULL, stagingID, fileName, 0);
        SET count = count + 1;
    END WHILE;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```